# Titanium - Draw an interactive doughtnut chart

Tags: android, jquery, html, titanium, pie-chart

I'm doing a Titanium app for Android and IOS. I want to show an interactive chart, similar to [snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery](http://www.elated.com/articles/snazzy-animated-pie-chart-html5-jquery/) or [pie-chart-with-html5-canvas-element](http://kumarjitc.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/pie-chart-with-html5-canvas-element.html).

I've created a web view and I add the html chart to this webview. It works ok on IOS, it shows the pie chart and interactivity works ok.

However, when I tried it on Android device, it shows the pie chart, but I'm not able to select the slice, so interactivity doesn't work.

On chart click event, the next code always return the same value, wherever I touch.

```
var mouseX = clickEvent.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var mouseY = clickEvent.pageY - this.offsetTop;
```

Do you know how I can solve it? Could I use another x,y?

I'm using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js. Do I have to use a specific jquery library for mobile?

Is this the best way to do it? Do you know another way? Like create the chart in Titanium from scratch, if it is possible....

Do you know an easy and customizable library to do this?

Thank you very much

**UPDATE**

I've also tried with jqplot library, and a simple interactive pie chart ([pie-donut-charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php)), and it happens the same. It is always highlight the same slice. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: usually people raphel js in titanium  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/make-a-stock-quote-app-displaying-charts-with-raphael-js/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking in use rapahel js, but like it uses svg instead of canvas, I think it doesn't work ok on Android 2.x, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved the problem, instead of using click event, I use ontouchend event:

```
document.ontouchend = function(e) {

   var mouseX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
   var mouseY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

   //Calculate if the touch was inside or outside the chart and do the correct action
}
```

I've tried it on Android and IOS, it works ok and get the position of the touch ok.